# `getServerSideProps` always returning 404 when deployed on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have recently started with NextJs and like it so far.

I have an index page where I am having server-side rendering. I have used `getServerSideProps` to do this.

I have the following code in my `index.js`

```js
import CardGrid from "../components/cardGrid";
import Header from "../components/header";
import ErrorPage from "next/error";
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";

function Home({
  wallData = []
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
        <div className="container mx-auto flex-grow">
          <CardGrid
            wallData={wallData}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
    },
  };
}

export default Home;
```

It's working fine when running locally but when I deployed it to Vercel, it always gives a 404 error.

I removed the use of `getServerSideProps` and deployed it, that time it worked on Vercel but with `getServerSideProps`, it just gave a 404 error.

Tried to check the Vercel logs but it's having no information at all.

```
MAR 21 23:39:17.29
404
xxxxxxxx.vercel.app
[GET] /
```

I tried to search a lot but could not get it to work, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you got any solution?